# Google ML Engine preprocessor_pb2 ImportError

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-ml

I'm attempting to run training through Google's ML Engine.

I mostly followed the steps in the following article to develop my training and test sets:
https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-taylor-swift-detector-with-the-tensorflow-object-detection-api-ml-engine-and-swift-82707f5b4a56

I continually run into the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 49, in <module> from object_detection import trainer File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 27, in <module> from object_detection.builders import preprocessor_builder File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py", line 21, in <module> from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2 ImportError: cannot import name preprocessor_pb2`

I cloned and followed the installation steps for object_detection, including the protobuf compilation and setting PYTHONPATH! The example `model_builder_test.py` also runs fine from the console.

My training job is as follows:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training my_training_job \
--job-dir=gs://myapp.appspot.com/train \
--packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
--module-name object_detection.train \
--region us-central1 \
--config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml \
-- \
--train_dir=gs://myapp.appspot.com/train \
--pipeline_config_path=gs://myapp.appspot.com/data/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config
```

`python -v` in the console returns version 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I resolved this one by changing the runtime version down to 1.2:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training my_training_job \
--runtime-version 1.2 \
--job-dir=gs://myapp.appspot.com/train \
--packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
--module-name object_detection.train \
--region us-central1 \
--config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml \
-- \
-- train_dir=gs://myapp.appspot.com/train \
-- pipeline_config_path=gs://myapp.appspot.com/data/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config
```

I subsequently received errors about missing matplotlib, and altered the following line to

```
models/research/setup.py

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['Pillow>=1.0', 'matplotlib']
```

and reran:

```
python setup.py sdist
(cd slim && python setup.py sdist)
```

I can't wait for Google to release more tools to make the training workflow easier!

Comment: FYI the default runtime-version is 1.4, so technically, you're buming up the version.

Comment: We'd love to hear more about your thoughts on making the workflow easier. Mind sending them to cloudml-feedback@google.com?

Comment: @rhaertel80 can we improve documentation regarding `data_augmentation_options`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. Mind sending your thoughts to cloudml-feedback@google.com?